# Unable to access CUPS /admin page. A TLS fatal alert has been received

Tags: chrome, openssl, ssl, cups

We have several servers where the CUPS /admin interface is utilized. It was brought to my attention that several of them are no longer functional. The config is fairly simple and I cannot find a difference between the configs of the working and non-working servers.

The error received in Chrome is simple "ERR_FAILED" and doesn't provide additional information under DETAILS.

The error reported in the CUPS error_log is:

```
D [29/Jun/2016:16:41:36 -0400] cupsdAcceptClient: skipping getpeercon()
D [29/Jun/2016:16:41:36 -0400] cupsdAcceptClient: 12 from 10.1.1.182:631 (IPv4)
D [29/Jun/2016:16:41:36 -0400] cupsdAcceptClient: skipping getpeercon()
D [29/Jun/2016:16:41:36 -0400] cupsdAcceptClient: 13 from 10.1.1.182:631 (IPv4)
E [29/Jun/2016:16:41:36 -0400] Unable to encrypt connection from 10.1.1.182 - A TLS fatal alert has been received.
D [29/Jun/2016:16:41:36 -0400] cupsdCloseClient: 13
E [29/Jun/2016:16:41:36 -0400] Unable to encrypt connection from 10.1.1.182 - A TLS fatal alert has been received.
D [29/Jun/2016:16:41:36 -0400] cupsdCloseClient: 12
```

The only potential change is that the IP address of the system was changed, but all of the systems were moved and not all are impacted.

I have tried cloning the configs. I have tried rebuilding the SSL certs. I've tried updating cups and openssl to the latest available packages.

Comment: Did you run cupsd using `-f` to run it on foreground.  Have you checked the permissions `/var/spool/cups/`.  Have you tried another browser?  What version of cups are you running.

Comment: Could it be due to SSLv3 being not supported anymore?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro   I don't believe it's an issue with SSLv3 as I have 2 nearly identical systems that are working properly.

Comment: @val0x00ff Running `cupsd -f` does nothing different. Nothing is logged to stdout/stderr it's all going to the log files.  Cups version is 1.4.2-74.el6 on RHEL 6.6.  Also I just checked with IE11 and it appears to work there.

Comment: @SeeJayEmm if it works with IE11 then there must be something with the certificates.  So you can put `DefaultEncryption Never` in `/etc/cups/cupsd.conf` and restart cups. See if this helps. Disabling SSL is not advised though, but just for the sake of debugging, you should give it a try.

Comment: Disabling encryption allows the page to be loaded w/o the HTTPS redirect. I had previously tried deleting and forcing the server to re-generate the SSL certs. This made no difference.

Answer (score 1):

We had the same issue. After regeneration of the CUPS server certificate (/etc/cups/ssl/server.crt) connection is working again. Might have to do sth with the SHA1 signature of the standard certificate.